# Django query "icontains" works only with numbers

Tags: python, django, search

My query:

```
result = Test.objects.filter(Q(description__icontains=data) | Q(code__icontains=data))
```

if 'data' in a number it works, if 'data' is a word not work,
why?

TY

EDIT:

models.py:

```
class Test(models.Model): 
code = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='00000000000000')
description = models.CharField(max_length=200,default = 'None')
```

an example of Test is: code: IPH0.2 description : IPHETENE GRADE 0.2 COD 260234

if I search 260 it work, if I search GRADE not work

'260' and 'GRADE' are example of "data"

Comment: Please, post your `models.py`

Comment: Also add some examples of `data`, `description`, `code`.

Comment: models:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='00000000000000')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,default = 'None')
```

Comment: an example of Test is:
code: IPH0.2
description : IPHETENE GRADE 0.2 COD 260234

if I search 260 it work, if I search GRADE not work

Comment: '260' and 'GRADE' are example of data

Comment: Please *edit* your question to add that information.

Comment: @JuConte Please edit the question to add `models.py`.

Comment: Are you sure `description` is properly set in the database? Can you inspect the database and ensure that the data is properly saved?